# Getting rid of embedded image border in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Is there any workaround to get rid of black 1px solid border which Google adds to images embedded inside the Sheet on mobile version?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your situation. What border are you talking about? If I add an image to a sheet in mobile, I don't see any border. Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: I've edited the original post with an example.

Comment: This is an image "over the cells".

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Can you provide an image URL that can be used to reproduce this?

Comment: It's just uploaded directly to the Sheet. It's really simple: Insert > Image > Over the cells. Then you open the sheet on mobile (not in application! just mobile version of the sheet's URL).

Comment: You're not talking about the spreadsheet itself but about the spreadsheet as [published it to the web](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965). In this case, this is reproducible in both mobile and desktop. I'm not sure whether this is intended behavior or not. I'd suggest you to report it by clicking `Help > Sheets Help` in the Sheets editor (there's no way to remove to customize this, so you cannot remove that border).